# What's the fastest way to expand url in python

Tags: python, url, expand

I have a checkin list which contains about 600000 checkins, and there is a url in each checkin, I need to expand them back to original long ones. I do so by

```
now = time.time()
files_without_url = 0
for i, checkin in enumerate(NYC_checkins):
    try:
        foursquare_url = urllib2.urlopen(re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", checkin[5]).group("url")).url
    except:
        files_without_url += 1

    if i%1000 == 0:
        print("from %d to %d: %2.5f seconds" %(i-1000, i, time.time()-now))
        now = time.time()
```

But this takes too long time: from 0 to 1000 checkins, it takes **3241 seconds**! Is this normal? What's the most efficient way to expand url by Python?

MODIFIED: Some Urls are from Bitly while some others are not, and I am not sure where they come from. In this case, I wanna simply use `urllib2` module.

for your information, here is an example of `checkin[5]`:

```
I'm at The Diner (2453 18th Street NW, Columbia Rd., Washington) w/ 4 others. http...... (this is the short url)
```

Comment: What do you mean by *'expand url'*?

Comment: Can you give an example of a value for `checkin[5]`?

Comment: It's taking *an hour* to process 1000 checkins?  That does seem excessive.  You could parallelize your code using, e.g., the multiprocessing module, but it seems like maybe something else is going on. @PeterWood "expand" probably == "resolve short url to the original url"

Comment: what kind of exceptions are expected by the way? all the `checkin[5]` has the pattern right?

Comment: @CPanda There might be some checkin[5] without urls, I am not sure about it so I add this exception

Comment: so there might be missing urls, unresponsive urls etc. right?

Comment: @CPanda probably, but since the checkin file is too big... I cannot check it manually...

Comment: @PeterWood I put example in my question, thanks

Comment: Maybe put the result of the regular expression into a variable before fetching the `url` in the `try/except` block. Print the failed `urls`. You might learn something about them.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would expand on my comment regarding the use of `multiprocessing` to speed up this task.

Let's start with a simple function that will take a url and resolve it as far as possible (following redirects until it gets a `200` response code):

```
import requests

def resolve_url(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        return (url, None)

    if r.status_code != 200:
        longurl = None
    else:
        longurl = r.url

    return (url, longurl)
```

This will either return a `(shorturl, longurl)` tuple, or it will
return `(shorturl, None)` in the event of a failure.

Now, we create a pool of workers:

```
import multiprocessing

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
```

And then ask our pool to resolve a list of urls:

```
resolved_urls = []
for shorturl, longurl in pool.map(resolve_url, urls):
    resolved_urls.append((shorturl, longurl))
```

Using the above code...

- With a pool of 10 workers, I can resolve 500 URLs in 900 seconds.
- If I increase the number of workers to 100, I can resolve 500 URLs in 30 seconds.
- If I increase the number of workers to 200, I can resolve 500 URLs in 25 seconds.

This is hopefully enough to get you started.

(NB: you could write a similar solution using the `threading` module rather than `multiprocessing`.  I usually just grab for `multiprocessing` first, but in this case either would work, and threading might even be slightly more efficient.)

Comment: thank you very much for your clear answer. I am sorry that I made a mistake: some urls are not from Bitly so requests may not work for some checkins..and I wanna simply use urllib2 module

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious how to accomplish the same thing using `urllib2` instead of requests.  This will work just fine for any URL; I tested it against Twitter URLs, since I didn't have a bunch of bit.ly links handy.

Comment: Thanks, actually I understand it. But why did you do `for shorturl, longurl in pool.map(resolve_url,urls):`, what if we simply do `resolved_urls = pool.map(resolve_urls, urls)`

Comment: You could absolutely do that.  I had originally had more in that loop before posting...

Comment: what do you mean by that? So if I do a for-loop as you did, I can know how many elements have been processed by resolve_url function if I check len(resolved_urls)?

Comment: I mean you could just do `resolved_urls = pool.map(resolve_urls, urls)` and it would be equivalent to the `for` loop in this example.

Answer (score -1):

Thread are most appropriate in case of network I/O. But you could try the following first.

```
pat = re.compile("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)") # always compile it
missing_urls = 0
bad_urls = 0
def check(checkin):
    match = pat.search(checkin[5])
    if not match:
        global missing_urls
        missing_urls += 1
    else:
        url = match.group("url")
        try:
            urllib2.urlopen(url) # don't lookup .url if you don't need it later
        except URLError: # or just Exception
            global bad_urls
            bad_urls += 1
for i, checkin in enumerate(NYC_checkins):
    check(checkin)
print(bad_urls, missing_urls)
```

If you get no improvement, now that we have a nice `check` function, create a *threadpool* and feed it. Speedup is guaranteed. Using processes for network I/O is pointless